# Prometheus relabeling not working as expected

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I would like to employ Prometheus' [relabeling](https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/) for adding a label `hostname`, which should be a more concise version of `instance` as provided by targets. This should allow more compact legends in Grafana dashboards.

For instance, when `__address__` has been set to `myhost.mydomain.com:8080`, `hostname` should be set to `myhost`. I am using `__address__` rather than `instance` as `source_label`, because the second is [apparently](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#%3Crelabel_config%3E) not yet set when relabeling occurs.

The relevant excerpt of my `prometheus.yaml` looks as follows (it is meant to employ a [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) regular expression):

```
- job_name: 'node_exporter'

  static_configs:
    - targets: ['myhost1.mydomain.com:8080',
                'myhost2.mydomain.com:8080']

  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: ['__address__']
      regex:         '^([^\.:]+?)'
      replacement:   ${1}
      target_label:  'hostname'
```

The expected new label `hostname` is not yet added. What could be wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this regex (with a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)) things have come to work: `'(.+?)(?:[\\.:].+)?'`.